# Quickly check if one region is inside or outside of another region using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, region

I have a segmented image that has been labeled and is shown below. I want to know how to quickly check if one region is inside or outside of another region, for example:

A is inside B, C is not inside (outside) B.

I've use the `regionprops` function, but can't find the corresponding features for it.

[image: Segmented Image]

Comment: The code in the linked duplicate gives a complete list of which regions contain which other regions. If you just want to do a quick check of one region versus another, the code within the for loop can be easily modified for that.

Comment: Thanks@gnovice! That code is exactly what I want